# Entering a character instead of integer

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using a do-while loop to print a menu to the screen. And I'm reading choice as an integer. The proplem is that if the user enter a character the program blows up. How can I avoid that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int menu() {            // prints the main menu of labs///
    int choice;
    printf("1)Lab 5 ( Repetetitions ).\n2)Lab 10 ( Passing 1D-Arrays to functions ).\n3)GPA Calculation.\n4)EXIT.\n\nEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}

int main() {
    int choice;

    do {

        choice = menu();
        if (choice != 4) {

            if (choice == 1)
                //lab5(choice);

            else if (choice == 2)
                //lab10(choice);


            else if (choice == 3)
                //  lab11(choice);
            else
                printf("invalid choice\n");
        }

    } while (choice != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To avoid that, read in a string and then convert it to an integer on your own.

Comment: Check the return from `scanf` to make sure it is good.  If it is not clear the buffer and try again.

Comment: the `main()` function would be much clearer as a simple `switch()` statement

Comment: a little humour here:  remove the explosive substance and the blasting cap from the program, then the user cannot 'blow it up'

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you, you need to check the return value of scanf

```
int menu() {            // prints the main menu of labs///
    int choice;
    printf("1)Lab 5 ( Repetetitions ).\n2)Lab 10 ( Passing 1D-Arrays to functions ).\n3)GPA Calculation.\n4)EXIT.\n\nEnter your choice: ");
    if(scanf("%d", &choice) == 1)
    {
        return choice;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scanf() (and family of functions) returns the number of successful conversions from the input buffer, if the conversion (%d) fails the function returns 0 (or EOF). In this case the character that could not be converted is not removed from buffer, this is why the endless loop occur, the conversion keeps failing for ever.

I used this [method](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) to flush the input buffer after the `scanf` call and the program behaved as expected.

[Run the program online](http://goo.gl/p2T0xe) (don't know for how long this will stay up)

```
void flushInput(){
  int c;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        /* discard */ ;  
}

int menu() {            // prints the main menu of labs///
    int choice;
    printf("1)Lab 5 ( Repetetitions ).\n2)Lab 10 ( Passing 1D-Arrays to functions ).\n3)GPA Calculation.\n4)EXIT.\n\nEnter your choice: ");
    if(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1){
        flushInput();
        return 0;
    }else{
        flushInput();
        return choice;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf`. Your code will flush bogus input but then it uses indeterminate value `choice` if input had failed.

Comment: it should flush the input whether the choice succeeds or not

Comment: also, some documentation say it returns EOF if conversion fails, but I checked and it returns 0 in that case. What is the official behaviour ?

Comment: Normally it returns the number of successful matches. `EOF` is only returned if it needed more characters in order to even start converting, but there were no more.

Comment: the `getchar()` function returns an 'int' and 'EOF' is an int.  so the line: `char c;` should be `int c;`   no other changes necessary to the `flushInput()` function.  Although I would strongly suggest checking for EOF before checking for some valid input like '\n'

Comment: regarding this statement: "The scanf function returns the number of characters read successfully from the input buffer"  That is not true!  The scanf() (and family of functions) returns the number of successful input conversions.  When successful, the returned value will match the number of format specifiers in the 'format' parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*USE This Code*/  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void orderAsk(int orderStorage[1]);
int main()
{     
    int orderStorage[1];
    orderAsk(orderStorage);
    printf("%d",orderStorage[0]);
    return 0;
}

void orderAsk(int orderStorage[1]){
    int d;
    d = scanf("%d", &orderStorage[0]);
    if ( d!= 1) {
        system("cls");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Error! Re-Enter\n");
        orderAsk(orderStorage);
    }
}
```