# Endless while loop when input a string to a variable that expected integer value

Tags: c, while-loop, integer, scanf

My C code as follows

```
int main() {
    int userInput = 0;

    while (userInput != 4) {
        printf("Enter a number : ");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

This normally work when input a integer value. But when input **a string value** it not asking again to a input. It goes to a endless loop printing the "Enter a number" phrase. Then, I tried the code as follows.

```
int main() {
    int userInput = 0;

    while (userInput != 4) {
        userInput = 0;             // reset the userInput value
        printf("Enter a number : ");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Even that not solved my problem. Why is this happening? How can it be fixed?

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf` to see if it succeeded. If the input does not match the format string, it remains in the stream and will be read (and failing) over and over.

Comment: Your `%d` format is only looking for integers.  It will stop if it sees a non-integer character.  So it's just looking at the same character over and over.  You'd be better off reading an entire line, then looking at what you read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entering a character instead of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299269/entering-a-character-instead-of-integer)

Comment: trueThari, Note that you are not entering a _string_ so much as a _line of text_, likely with a terminating `'\n'`.  A _string_ in C is character array with a terminating _null chracter_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to free the input buffer from an invalid data. Something like the following.

```
do
{
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    if ( scanf("%d", &userInput) != 1 )
    {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
        userInput = 0;
    }
} while ( userInput != 4 );
```

Another approach is to use the function `fgets` to read the whole string in a character array and then convert it to an integer using `strtol` and check whether the conversion was successful.

Comment: Can you explain what "%*[^\n]" does?

Comment: @trueThari It means to read all symbols in the input buffer until the new line character '\n' is encountered but do not store them in an array.

Answer (score 1):

> *"This normally work when input a integer value. But when input a string value it not asking again to a input."*

If a data scan is not converted by `scanf()`, the input stream, in this case `stdin`, is not advanced.  When `scanf()` is called again, it will attempt to scan & convert the same data from the same incorrect input, with the same result.  This is what causes your infinite loop. Inputting alpha characters when `scanf() is setup to convert numeric characters will always fail.

The good news is [scanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) returns a value indicating how many items were converted successfully.  *alpha*  input scanned using the `%d` format specifier, should result in converting zero items.  Code using `scanf()` should always check it's return value:

```
int num_converted = scanf("%d", &userInput);
if(num_converted != 1) 
{
     //handle error 
     ...
}
```

As an aside, `scanf()` is considered by many as as [sub-optimal method for handling user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).  For example

> *"...it will tell you whether it succeeded or failed, but can tell you only approximately where it failed, and not at all how or why. You
> have very little opportunity to do any error recovery."*
> (*[jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430957/645128)*).

Consider an alternative method based on using `fgets()`.

The following reads the entire input line into a buffer, eliminates unwanted white space and validates input.  Only then does it convert the input buffer to the specified type...

```
int main(void) {
    int userInput = 0;
    char inBuf[20] = {0};
    
    printf("Enter a number : ");
    //int num = scanf("%d", &userInput);
    while (fgets(inBuf, sizeof inBuf, stdin)) {
        inBuf[strcspn(inBuf, "\r\n")] = 0;//remove unwanted white space
        if(digits_only(inBuf))//example validation for numeric only input
        {
            userInput = atoi(inBuf);
            printf("\n%d entered, and converted!\n\nctrl-c to exit\n...Or enter a number : \n", userInput);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n%s contains non-numeric characters, it cannot be converted.\n\nctrl-c to exit\n...Or enter a number : \n", inBuf);
        }
    };
    return 0;
}

//test for numeric only input   
//(note that other validations can be coded with expansions 
//to accommodate float or double, alpha only, etc.)    
bool digits_only(const char *in)
{
    while(*in)
    {
        if(!isdigit(*in)) return false;
        in++;
    }
    return true;
}
```